# Accessing object key with dot notation and space

Tags: javascript

I came across the following:

```
var object = {};
object.name = 'ABC';
console.log(object.     name); // this is still valid
```

Notice the space after `object.`

Why is this valid? Is there any ECMA specification for this?

Same is true for all the inherited properties for different data types.

I've tested this on a node terminal.

Thanks!

Comment: You see that sort of thing all the time in method chaining, with every `.prop(something)` on a new line

Comment: `.` is an operator like many others. You wouldn't be surprised by a large number of spaces around a `+`, would you?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca - That is ***very*** well put. Stole it and made the answer a CW. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why is this valid?

Because whitespace is *largely* (though **not** entirely) irrelevant in the JavaScript syntax. You can safely insert any whitespace other than a line break between two tokens (and in most, but **not** all cases, you can insert line breaks as well; the "most" is due to [ASI](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-automatic-semicolon-insertion)). You can't insert spaces *within* tokens (because it breaks them up into two tokens), but you can *between* tokens.

As [Federico klez Culloca](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133203/federico-klez-culloca) points out ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53334750/accessing-object-key-with-dot-notation-and-space/53334789#comment93548670_53334750)), `.` is an operator, just like `+` or `*`. The fact we generally don't put spaces around it, but do put spaces around them, is simply convention.

These are all valid:

```
console.log(object.name);
console.log(
    object.name
);
console.log(
    object . name
);
console.log(
    object
    .
    name
);
```

> Is there any ECMA specification for this?

Of course, [the specification itself](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/). Specifically [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-property-accessors) and [here](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-lexical-and-regexp-grammars). From that last link:

> Input elements other than white space and comments form the terminal symbols for the syntactic grammar for ECMAScript and are called ECMAScript tokens. These tokens are the reserved words, identifiers, literals, and punctuators of the ECMAScript language. Moreover, line terminators, although not considered to be tokens, also become part of the stream of input elements and guide the process of automatic semicolon insertion (11.9). **Simple white space and single-line comments are discarded and do not appear in the stream of input elements for the syntactic grammar.**

Comment: *Simple white space and single-line comments are discarded and do not appear in the stream of input elements for the syntactic grammar* appears to be the relevant sentence.

Comment: Thank You! +1 and accepted.
*Edit:* Need to wait 5 mins before I can accept